# SQL string equality comparison with EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've just realised that there is a problem with a couple of triggers I have written which can be demonstrated with this query here:

`SELECT CASE WHEN 'TEST' = 'TEST      ' THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END`

Whilst you might think that this resolves to N, it in fact resolves to Y as SQL Server trims the trailing spaces from strings before comparing them in this way.

One suggestion appears to be to use like, which is fine in a where clause:

`SELECT CASE WHEN 'TEST' LIKE 'TEST      ' THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END` does indeed resolve to n as you would hope.

Another suggestion is to check the length too, using `DATALENGTH:

`SELECT CASE WHEN 'TEST' = 'TEST      ' AND DATALENGTH('TEST') = DATALENGTH('TEST      ') THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END`

Unfortuantely, this is going to cause extra complexity in a trigger I use to update another table:

```
SELECT
    FullName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT
    FullName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM TableB
```

Which then becomes:

```
SELECT
    FullName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
    FullName_Length = DATALENGTH(FullName)
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT
    FullName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
    FullName_Length = DATALENGTH(FullName)
FROM TableB
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Is there some way I can tell `EXCEPT` to compare strings including their length rather than by trimming the trailing characters?

Apologies if this has been asked before, I haven't been very lucky with finding anything specifically looking at `EXCEPT`.

Comment: Why not check the length and the equality?

Comment: Cast 'TEST    ' to a Char(8) ?

Comment: @Kermit I was hoping that there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could add something at the end

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN CONCAT('TEST', 'ADummyValue') = 
             CONCAT('TEST      ', 'ADummyValue') THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END


SELECT
    CONCAT(FullName, 'ADummyValue') AS FullName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT
    CONCAT(FullName, 'ADummyValue') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM TableB
```

Using REVERSE

```
SELECT
    REVERSE(FullName) AS FullName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT
    REVERSE(FullName) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
FROM TableB
```

Comment: I've been hoping to avoid it as it seems a bit hacky :( It's beginning to look like this may be the only way to go.

Comment: @john: if you don;t have leading spaces you could use REVERSE too

Comment: From the point of view of performance, I would assume the first one is more efficient. Hopefully someone else might know some undocumented or little known feature that avoids any of these little hacks. If not, I'll probably have to do it this way. +1 anyway

Comment: I guess nobody else is going to weigh in then.